# Pass an integer as a parameter in an Alamofire PUT request

Tags: swift, rest, alamofire, put

So I am trying to do a PUT request using Alamofire and I need an integer parameter (not an object). 
The request sends an id to the database and the query makes an update to an object with that id in the database.
The Parameters object in alamofire seems to take only objects:

```
var parameters: Parameters = ["key" : "value"]
```

is there any way to just send an integer without using the object?
The error I keep getting when I use that method above is:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token
```

and I am assuming this means I am passing an object when I should be passing an int instead.

This is my request :

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).response{ response in
        if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            // pass
        }else{
            // fail
        }
        completionHandler((response.response?.statusCode)!)
    }
```

I can't seem to find any examples that have to do with us online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give more information about where you are sending the request, then I can test my solution to see if it works. But you can try this.

```
let url = "YOUR_URL"

let yourData = "WHATEVER CUSTOM VAL YOU WANT TO PASS"

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
//request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") //This is if you want to have headers. But it doesn't look like you need them. 

request.httpBody  = yourData
/*
do {
    request.httpBody  = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: yourData)
} catch {
    print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
}
*/
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {(response) in
    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
        print ("pass")
    }else{
        print ("fail")
    }
    completionHandler((response.response?.statusCode)!)

    /*
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        print ("success: \(value)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: its a localhost db, but I tried this and I got this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'

Comment: it is hard for me to test what you are doing without more information or an api to actually use to test it. but try what I just changed.

Comment: okay, I just added more description, if that could help. Also, the data I am sending is an integer, not a string. I tried this too but httpBody does not seem to accept an int as data, just string

Comment: so then convert it to a string and give it a try like this `String(describing: yourData)`

Comment: omg it worked! It gave me a 415 at first so I commented out the headers and tried again, and it works perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!